# Codeception in Yii2, every test in a row consume more memory

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I am trying to test a class using Codeception in Yii2 advanced template.
And it uses too much memory, when i run all the tests.

When i run tests separately they are fast and don't use much memory, they all take about 10 mb, which is ok for me.
But when i run them all, every test in a row uses more and more memory, and for example 6 tests use 645mb together.

I suppose they don't clean memory somehow.
How do i clean memory after each test?

It happened after codeception update, to 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem.
I used [Codeception/Specify](https://github.com/Codeception/Specify) blocks, which deep cloned everything.

I disabled cloning by default, setting the following in _bootstrap.php
`\Codeception\Specify\Config::setDeepClone(false);`

More info can be found in the docs:
https://github.com/Codeception/Specify#global-configuration